# 'no such file to load -- bootstrap-sass' using compass and ruby version 2.3 instead of 1.8

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, osx-mountain-lion, compass, bootstrap-sass

Wishing to migrate I am trying to install and use an existing compass project using 'bootstrap-sass' on a server with OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion installed. So far I've installed xCode, xCode Command Line Tools, Homebrew, Git, Compass and updated Ruby since version 1.8.7 ships with OSX Mountain Lion.

When using 'compass watch' or even 'compass create' I receive the following error. It looks like somehow compass uses the old ruby installation version 1.8.7.

```
LoadError on line 31 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- bootstrap-sass
```

Additional information

```
$ compass --version
Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)

$ which compass
/usr/bin/compass

$ ruby version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
$ brew docter
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
```

Adding /usr/local/bin prior to the $PATH at ~/.bash_profile resolved the issue.